# Method to make corn pasta?

Tags: pasta, noodles, corn, gluten-free

I've been unwell for quite awhile now and corn pasta has been a lifer saver because it's fairly easy to digest (for me.)

Anyway, i'm curious as to how exactly they are made. For instance look at this product:

http://www.leveneziane.it/en/gluten-free-pasta/tubetti-corn-pasta

The ingredients are simply corn flour and an emulsifier, but if you take a look online for any homemade corn pasta recipes you will surely find mostly complex recipes with many ingredients. An ingredient list of size two that creates pasta with such a good texture is hard to believe! I'd LOVE to know their full process ^_^.

Does anyone have any experience in this field? I'd love to make my own and learn the process - but I don't want a complex homemade recipe with 10+ ingredients as those are sometimes harder to digest for me :(

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have a [pasta roller](http://www.amazon.com/Roma-Traditional-Style-Pasta-Machine/dp/B000ATUKBK/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1397992421&sr=1-1&keywords=pasta+roller)?

Comment: Also, related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37256/masa-harina-and-a-pasta-roller

Comment: Consider Polenta. It's easy to make, and the firm version cuts nicely into pasta like shapes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polenta

Comment: I do have a pasta roller,  not really a fan of pollenta hehe

Comment: I am not sure this is indeed the complete list of ingredients, especially because there is nothing inside to bind the pasta and prevent it from falling apart. Is it possible that Italian law allows producers to leave out ingredients if used in very small amounts? Many binders are added in sub-percent ratios. Besides, it doesn't say what was done to the corn. It could be in the form of modified starch, and you can never know what exactly they did to the starch to get it to glue together.

Comment: How about just buying store made polenta? You can sauce it much the same way you sauce pasta. Grill it or pan fry it first.

Comment: @rumtscho I'm sorry for the ignorance, but I do not see what kind of things would be needed to keep the pasta together. Wheat pasta has only wheat flour and water as ingredients, why not also corn pasta?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano what keeps wheat pasta together is a protein called gluten. It is contained in wheat (wheat flour is ~10% gluten and ~90% starch, roughly calculated). Most other grains don't contain gluten, except ones which are very closely related to wheat (e.g. spelt). Corn has no gluten at all.

Answer (score 2):

In korean cuisine, corn noodles are made with powdered elm root as the binding agent as it has the starchy glutinous qualities missing from corn. Maybe you could see about that or try getting some corn noodles from a korean grocer?

Answer (score 0):

I have three thoughts relating to your dilemma, and I have some bad news.  I think the execution of these noodles relies on techology and an ingredient you may find difficult to aquire and utilize.  Starches go through a variety of predictable physical changes when water, fat, and heat are introduced to them.  (There are many well-written posts about this.)

Tightly controlling the timing of heating, hydration, and cooling rate with calibrated industrial equipment and using forms/molds is most likely a large part of its finished appeal.

The emulsifier that is being used (E471) was probably selected for its specific interactions with the starch profile that the corn noodle is based on (probably something *really* starchy, 100g had 354kcals and 78g or so were listed as carbohydrates) This is a commercial food additive and may be hard to source. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono-_and_diglycerides_of_fatty_acids

Good luck on your simple gluten free noodle recipe quest.

Answer (score 0):

Corn Noodles are easy to make. Let's go to Moma's kitchen and watch her make some ;-)

LET'S COOK IT TOGETHER - http://bit.ly/1fBpPOj

RECIPE: 500 gr. Cornflour, 5 eggs, Salt, Parmesan (optional), 2 tbsp olive oil

Comment: It helps if you actually link to the [specific recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyDpYGu04jA&list=PLAXOzWQ-ya6F86hPA3Ka3Gq7_vsdKKUJ2).  We generally don't like link-only answers ... although you gave the recipie (and it's just mix it all together), she also mentions that because it has no gluten, it's better to roll out by hand rather than a machine.  (she does use a stand mixer for combining).